# Vector flux through a segment of a sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Given the vector field $\vec A(\vec r) = \vec r$, I have to calculate the vector flux through a sphere whose center is located in the origin. 
I want to apply Gauß-Theorem and use spherical coordinates.

The vector field in spherical coordinates is $\vec A (\vec r) = \begin{pmatrix} r \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Now I have to calculate $\int \vec A d\vec F$, and here i am very unsure what $\vec F$ is because I never did it in spherical coordinates.

My attempt is $\vec F = \vec e_r = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi)\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) \\ \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}d\phi d\theta$ .

Is this correct and if no, what did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d\vec{F}$ is the vector pointing out of the infinitesimal area element of your sphere. Therefore: $d\vec{F}=dS\cdot\vec{n}$, where $dS=r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ and $\vec{n}=\vec{r}$ (by symmetry of the problem).

Comment: why $r^2 \sin(\theta) $ ? I know this as "volume element", is there a deeper meaning of that or is it just coincidence?

Comment: The *surface* element is $r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\theta$. Imagine a small square on the surface of your sphere. The "vertical" side is equal to an arc of angle $d\theta$, i.e. the length (angle times radius) is $r\cdot d\theta$. The "horizontal" side of the square is again an arc, this time of angle $d\phi$, but with the radius of a small circle, given by $r\cdot\sin\theta$. The surface area of the square is then $r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.
If you want the *volume* element, you move from a square to a cube, i.e. you also integrate with respect to $r$: $dV=r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi dr$.

Comment: Thanks so far, I must admit I quite don't get the idea concerning the surface element, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: It is quite hard to explain without looking at a [nice diagram like this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3LPIA.jpg) :)